# How to Access Static class elements in all java classes

Tags: android-studio

I want to access static class members in all classes present in different java files with just name i dont want to use it with class name and then member name .

In mainactivity i import import static com.example.myapplication.MemoryMappedVariables.*;
and use members with name only like Base_Absolute_Val=2530; so it works fine and do not show any error on other hand if i do same it shows error and say to include class name like MemoryMappedVariables.Base_Absolute_Val how can i resolve this .